# What is the difference between a linearly independent set and a spanning set?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

Is a spanning set not just a linearly independent set of vectors, or is there a difference?

The context of this question being the following theorem:

"In any vector space, if $|I|$ is a linearly independent set and $|S|$ is a spanning set, then $|I| \leq |S|$"

Comment: Why don't you write down the definitions of the two notions? You can easily see that these are different concepts.

Comment: In hindsight, I agree with you. I suppose I shouldn't be working this late. Apologies.

Comment: {Led Zeppelin, Elvis, Jimi Hendrix} is a linearly independent set, but do not generate the vector space $rock$. And any two musics of the vector space $biebermusics$ form a spanning set which is not linearly independent.

Comment: In the vector space of colors used in electronic visual devices, the set {Red,Green,Blue} is a basis (both LI and spanning).Addition of a color say brown spoils its LI property only.

Answer (score 4):

A set of vectors can be spanning without being linearly independent and vice versa. Compare the definitions:

> A set of vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ *spans* a vector space $V$ if every vector $x \in V$ is a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.

For example, the set of vectors $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$, as does the set of vectors $\{(1, 0), (0, 1), (\pi, \sqrt{2})\}$.

> A set of vectors $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is *linearly independent* if whenever $\alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n = 0$, it must be the case that $\alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_n = 0$.

For example, the set of vectors $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as is the set of vectors $\{(1, 0)\}$.

However, the spanning set $\{(1, 0), (0, 1), (\pi, \sqrt{2})\}$ is *not* linearly independent, since
$$
-\pi(1,0) - \sqrt{2} (0, 1) + (\pi, \sqrt{2}) = (0, 0),
$$
but $-\pi \neq 0$ and $-\sqrt{2} \neq 0$.
Moreover, the linearly independent set $\{(1, 0\}$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^2$ since, for example, $(0,1)$ is not a scalar multiple of $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ is a spanning set of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ but is not linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $k$ be a field and $V$ be a $k$-vector space. Let $S\subset V$ be a finite set, $S$ is said to be a spanning set of $V$ if and only if each element of $V$ can be express as a finite linearly combination of elements in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, in $\mathbb R^3$ the set $$\{ (1,0,0), (0,1,1) \}$$ is linearly independent meaning no member of the set can be written as a linear combination of other members of that set. But linear combinations of those vectors clearly don't span $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

A spanning set is a set of vectors who when combined in all possible combinations cover the space equal to some $R^n$.

However, many of these vectors might just be scalar multiples of each other. As a result, many are redundant and serve no purpose towards covering $R^n$. If you remove all the ones that can be expressed as some linear combination of the others, you are left with a "linearly independent" set of vectors that still span over all of $R^n$.